# How to use tag in the output path of fluentd?

Tags: fluentd

I'm trying to use fluentd to copy a bunch of log files. All log files need to be written to the same destination directory.

```
      @type tail
      @id container-input
      format none
      path "/var/log/containers/plugin*.log"
# This path would match multiple files that I want to log
      pos_file "/var/log/plugin.log.pos"
      refresh_interval 5
      rotate_wait 5
      read_from_head "true"
      tag plugin.*
    </source>
    <filter plugin.**>
      @type record_transformer
      <record>
        filename ${tag_suffix[-2]}
      </record>
    </filter>
    <match plugin**>
      @type file
      path /destlogs/plugin.log
    </match>
```

What I want is to use the filename somewhere in the output path, something like

`path /destlogs/plugin-${filename}.log`

However when I use such configuration, fluentd does not pick the filename tag as a variable, rather it just creates the path as is.

How to use a tag as a variable in the output path?

Comment: Try: `path "/destlogs/plugin-#{ record['filename'] }.log"`

Comment: @Azeem ```/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/fluentd-0.12.43/lib/fluent/config/literal_parser.rb:165:in instance_eval': undefined local variable or method record' for #<Binding:0x0000562b87bf8430> (NameError) ``` seeing this error when using your suggested line.

Comment: You need to configure it with the fields that you want to use in the filename format. See: https://docs.fluentd.org/output/file#path. `key1` here represents the `record` field. So, in addition to what you're doing i.e. `path /destlogs/plugin-${filename}`, you need to configure `buffer` under `match` e.g. `<buffer filename> ... </buffer>`.

Comment: This is also relevant for you: https://docs.fluentd.org/output/file#append.

Comment: `path "/containerlogs/infoscalecontainers-${tag}-${filename}.log"
<buffer tag, filename>
flush_interval 5s
</buffer>`
Even with this all I see is

`# ls /containerlogs/`

`infoscalecontainers-${tag}-${filename}.log.20210801.b5c8762156e800eff`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here was the version. v0.12 seems to not support tags in the match section, whereas v1.0 does. I was using fluentd image
`fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:elasticsearch` Which I realized uses the older fluentd version. Updating it to
`fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1-debian-elasticsearch` resolved the issue.